# How to use img-fluid, set a custom height and not deform the image?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-images

I have an image that is fluid (`.img-fluid`) and I've set a height of 245px and it's width is always 100%. When I check my page on small devices, the height works just fine, but the image looks squeezed in it's width. My image must always looks correctly, not squeezed.

[image]

```html
<div class="product-image">
    <img src="https://static.reverb-assets.com/assets/homepage/open-graph- 
    7c32c7390769b2d0ab9366d1547b0a829b1c44f2eb991a9b0d1b3f59d0e62bf4.jpg" 
    alt="Foto del producto" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

```css
.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 245px;
}

.product-image .img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `object-fit` CSS property should fit your needs.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 245px;
}

.img--cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img--contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.talentz.net/wp-content/uploads/CG10-2.jpg" alt="Foto del producto" class="img--cover">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://www.talentz.net/wp-content/uploads/CG10-2.jpg" alt="Foto del producto" class="img--contain">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on both sides of the image an `auto` value

```
<div class="product-image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x245.png" alt="Foto" class="img-fluid">
</div>

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 245px;
}
.product-image .img-fluid {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```